# numpy randint arguments exclusive

Tags: python, numpy, random

In the [official NumPy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html),
`numpy.random.randint` has an exclusive second argument.

```
random.randint(low, high=None, size=None, dtype=int)
    Return random integers from low (inclusive) to high (exclusive).
```

Then, I thought `random.randint(1, 5)` returns values 1, 2, 3, or 4,
but it actually gives values among 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You’re conflating `numpy.random.randint` with Python’s [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) (from the `random` module in the standard library), the latter of which has an inclusive upper bound.